# Why does my SVT-HEVC-encoded video run out of sync?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, encoding, video-encoding

I'm trying to transcode a video (with audio) to HEVC using [Intel's SVT-HEVC encoder](https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-HEVC). The video's audio tracks are in sync before transcoding.

Both `ffprobe` and `mediainfo` agree that the input video is at 23.98 fps (24 / 1.001):

```
# ffprobe
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1872x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 26:15], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)

# mediainfo
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Width                                    : 1 872 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.733
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
```

Now I've constructed the following `ffmpeg` + `SvtHevcEncApp` command-line on my Linux system to transcode this video into H.265:

```
inputFile="testmovie.mp4"
outputFile="testmovie.hevc"

: ${frameCount:=68808}
: ${videoWidth:=1872}
: ${videoHeight:=1080}
: ${videoBitRate:=2359296}
: ${videoFrameRateNum:=24000}
: ${videoFrameRateDenom:=1001}

ffmpeg \
        -hide_banner \
        -i "$inputFile" \
        -nostdin \
        -f rawvideo \
        -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        - | SvtHevcEncApp \
                -i stdin \
                -n $frameCount \
                -w $videoWidth \
                -h $videoHeight \
                -rc 1 \
                -tbr $videoBitRate \
                -fps-num $videoFrameRateNum \
                -fps-denom $videoFrameRateDenom \
                -profile main \
                -encMode 0 \
                -bit-depth 8 \
                -tier main \
                -b "$outputFile"
```

I can then observe how `ffmpeg` hands the frames over to `SvtHevcEncApp` and the latter encodes them into an `.hevc` stream.

My problem is that when I remux the `.hevc` stream with the audio tracks, they quickly run out of sync (1 minute into the clip, the audio track is more than 1 second off already). Despite both the original clip and the transcoded clip showing 23.98 fps in `ffprobe` and `mediainfo`.

A scene that happens in the original clip at 62.042 seconds happens in the HEVC clip at 59.542 seconds. Since it isn't playing at a faster framerate, it `SvtHevcEncApp` must be skipping/losing frames.

What could be going wrong here?
Is it possible that `ffmpeg` alters the frame rate (i.e. duplicates some frames) as it outputs them to `stdout`?

Comment: If you extract the avc stream (with `-f h264 -c:v copy`) and then remux it like you did with the hevc one, does the problem occur?

Comment: I tested this with `ffmpeg -i testmovie.mp4 -c:v copy videoonly.mp4` and on a raw AVC stream via `mkvextract -i testmovie.mkv tracks 0:videoonly.avc`, then remuxed with `mkvtoolnix`. In both cases, video + audio remained perfectly in sync. Transcoding with the built-in libx265 also avoids the issue (but takes weeks rather than hours).

Answer (score 0):

I never found out why the audio runs out of sync, except some vague feeling that MKVtoolnix may not be figuring out the framerate of the `.hevc` file correctly.

My workaround so far has been to convert the `.hevc` file to `.mkv` with some very specific parameters:

```
mkvOutputFile=${outputFile%.*}.mkv

mkvmergeParameters=()
mkvmergeParameters+=(--default-duration 0:${videoFrameRateNum}/${videoFrameRateDenom}fps)
mkvmergeParameters+=(--fix-bitstream-timing-information 0)
mkvmerge \
    "${mkvmergeParameters[@]}" \
    "$outputFile" \
    -o "$mkvOutputFile"
```

This produces an `.mkv` file from the `.hevc` file that will continue to play at the correct frame rate when muxed with other streams (i.e. audio).